# Java array sort help: How to execute this on inputting on scanners

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
inp1 = getinp1();
inp2 = getinp2();
inp3 = getinp3();
inp4 = getinp4();
inp5 = getinp5();

int[] numbers = {inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4,inp5};
Arrays.sort(numbers);

System.out.println("The highest number is "+numbers[2]);
System.out.println("The middle number is "+numbers[1]);
System.out.println("The lowest number is "+numbers[0]);
```

The output are showing only inp3, inp4 , inp5 but it must need to mix with other inputs so that it could make a right decision what is highest middle and smallest value

Comment: Why do you believe the middle number is in the second position of the array (`numbers[1]`) and the highest number is in the third position (`numbers[2]`).  That is not how `sort` works.

Comment: What's the best way to remedy this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the above Code the index which you have mentioned is wrong. It should be like below.

```
    System.out.println("The highest number is "+numbers[numbers.length-1]);
    System.out.println("The middle number is "+numbers[2]);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is "+numbers[0]);
```

Comment: What if the array has an even number of elements? Which is the "middle" number?

Comment: Then we can go with this logic.
  System.out.println("The highest number is "+numbers[numbers.length-1]);
     System.out.println("The middle number is "+numbers[numbers.length/2]);
     System.out.println("The lowest number is "+numbers[0]);.